# Navigate to specific route in another navigator (React Native)

Tags: react-native, navigation

I have the next route of code:

```
const Main = DrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard: {screen: TopNavigation},
  SetupSignUp: {screen: SetupSignUp},
},{
  initialRouteName: "Dashboard",
});

export const App = StackNavigator({
  Welcome: {screen: Welcome},
  Main: {screen: Main},
  Login: {screen: Login},
  SignUp: {screen: SignUp},
  Content: {screen: MainStack},
  SetupSignUp: {screen: }
},{
  initialRouteName: "Welcome",
});
```

My app start in App.

What i want is in the route of SetupSignUp from App, go to Main but in SetupSignUp, this without change the initialRouteName because i need this for use in Content.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're combining Drawer and StackNavigator in the wrong way.

I made this example to try to help: 
https://github.com/juliancorrea/react-native-navigation-example/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to externalize your route definitions and create two similar drawer navigators with different initial routes:

```
const mainConfig = {};

const mainRoutes = {
  Dashboard: {screen: TopNavigation},
  SetupSignUp: {screen: SetupSignUp},
};

const Main = DrawerNavigator(mainRoutes, {
  ...mainConfig
  initialRouteName: "Dashboard",
});

const AlternativeMain = DrawerNavigator(mainRoutes, {
  ...mainConfig
  initialRouteName: "SetupSignUp",
});
```

Then, you will be able to navigate to Main or to AlternativeMain with different initial routes.